# Crontab - run a command every 5th min after 9:15am

Tags: cron

I want to run a program every 5th mins between 9:15am and 3:30pm.

```
5 * * * MON-FRI
```

seems to run the program every 5 mins (as expected) but its critical to run it only after 9:15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create several records in cron to accomplish what you want:

```
15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 9 * * MON-FRI /path/to/program
*/5 10-14 * * MON-FRI /path/to/program
0,5,10,15,20,25,30 15 * * MON-FRI /path/to/program
```

The other way is to incorporate the logic in you program

Talking about programming way this is sample shell script which will check if you are between Monday and Friday and between 9:15 and 15:30

```
date +"$u %H %M"|awk '{t=$2*60+$3; if ($1>=1 && $1<6 && t>=555 && t<=930) print 1; else print 0;}'
```

This command will print 1 if you are in to the interval of run the things and 0 if you are outside. And then you need to run the script every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/program
```

Comment: `The other way is to incorporate the login in your program` - was not completely clear. Will test the crontab entries

Comment: @Ved, check my edited answer with sample code how to check in script

Comment: @Ved, i mean logic, not login :)